# How to solve a logic theorem containing disjunction and universal quantifier?

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Dos anyone know how to solve the following theorem?

$$⊢∀x(F[x] ∨ p) \iff (∀xF[x] ∨ p)$$

I managed to solve it from right to left, but not from left to right.

Comment: Is $x$ free in $P$?

Comment: For left to right, you'll probably need to do something like apply excluded middle to $p$, or use proof by contradiction.

Comment: *How* do you need to solve it?  Using equivalences, a formal proof, formal semantics, other?

Comment: One doesn't "solve" theorems, one *proves* them.

Comment: For the left-to-right implication, argue by cases. If $p$ is true, then the right side is true by the meaning of $\lor$. If $p$ is false, then on the left side $F[x]\lor p$ is equivalent to just $F[x]$, so the left side simplifies to $\forall x\,F[x]$, and again the right side follows. As @DanielSchepler suggested, the use of excluded middle here is essential. The left-to-right implication is not valid in intuitionistic logic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a formal proof in Fitch:
[image]

Comment: I wonder if it might make things a bit simpler to use proof by contradiction on the disjunction from the start, then prove from $\lnot (\forall x ~ F(x) \vee P)$ that $\lnot \forall x ~ F(x)$ and $\lnot P$, then prove also $\forall x F(x)$ using the original hypothesis and $\lnot P$.